# Docker run issue: Invalid value: File does not exist

Tags: docker, deployment, streamlit, ovh

I am new to Docker. Basically, this is the content of my Dockerfile:

[Dockerfile content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xlG7.png)

I have ran this command for building the image:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t cdr_performance_tracker:latest .
```

And it was successfully completed.

Then when I ran it using the following command:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 cdr_performance_tracker
```

I get the following error:
**Invalid value: File does not exist: Main.py**

And my file structure for this project is:
cdr_performance_tracker folder

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFzw8.png)

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: You seem to have provided just the words "Dockerfile content" in place of the actual Dockerfile.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the link with the actual contents of the Dockerfile, or enough of it to reproduce the problem?  For example, do you `COPY` the actual Python code into the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are setting the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile to `/app`
then you copy the root directory of the project to the `/app` inside the container. meaning the path to the `Main.py` would be `/app/app/Main.py`

When you run the `CMD` you are in the workdir. there you need to reference the relative path to `Main.py` which is `./app/Main.py` or absolute path which is `/app/app/Main.py`